# @ngrx 4 how to filter current loaded data

Tags: ngrx

I am working on a new angular 4 plus @ngrx 4 project.

I wish to have a searching function on the loaded data.

For example, all the contacts info have been loaded in the component.
The contacts list will be filtered which contact name matched with the search text.

[Please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nRBj.png)

As the data is existed in store and I do not wish to call web api service again.

Any idea or demo code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow this flow to search what you need on already fetched content:

Use something like `'(input)'='searchInputChange$.next(search)'` in your input. So, each time the user changes the input, it will trigger our research.

Then, on your component, on the constructor, each time `searchInputChange$` changes, we trigger a new `SearchAction`. Then, we will change our filtered contents on the reducers and the result will be inserted into `contents$`. On `ngOnInit` we just load the data from api the first time.

I'm using a model called `Content`, just an example, that has a string parameter `title`. We will use this field to filter our contents based on the search input.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';

/** ngrx **/
import {AppState} from '../../app-state.interface';
import * as searchActions from './actions/search.actions';

/** App Models **/
import { Content } from './models/content.model';

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

    searchInputChange$ = new Subject<string>();
    contents$: Observable<Array<Content>>;

    constructor(private _store: Store<AppState>) {
      this.searchInputChange$
        .switchMap((text: string) => of(text))
        .subscribe((text: string) => this._store.dispatch(new searchActions.SearchAction(text)));
      this.contents$ = this._store.select(getSearchedContents);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._store.dispatch(new searchActions.LoadAction());
    }

}
```

Then, we'll have our `SearchActions`. `Load` is triggered on the init of our component, fetches some contents from api. `LoadSuccess` is emitted on the effect of the load action in order to populate our reducer with fetched data and show it in our first component, this has a payload of an array of contents. `Search` will be triggered on change of our input field, this will have a string payload containing the search string.

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

/** App Models **/
import { Content } from '../models/content.model';

export const LOAD = '[Search] Load';
export const LOAD_SUCCESS = '[Search] Load Success';
export const SEARCH = '[Search] Search';

export class LoadAction implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD;
  constructor() { }
}

export class LoadActionSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD_SUCCESS;
  constructor(public payload: Content[]) { }
}

export class SearchAction implements Action {
  readonly type =  SEARCH;
  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}

export type All
  = LoadAction
  | LoadActionSuccess
  | SearchAction;
```

**SearchEffect** that will just fetch contents from api:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect } from '@ngrx/effects';

/** rxjs **/
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import {mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators/mergeMap';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';

/** ngrx **/
import * as searchActions from '../actions/search.actions';

/** App Services **/
import { SomeService } from '../services/some.service';

/** App Model **/
import {Content} from '../models/content.model';

@Injectable()
export class SearchEffects {

  @Effect() load$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(searchActions.LOAD)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => {
          return this.someService.getContentsFromApi()
            .pipe(
              map((contents: Content[]) => {
                return new searchActions.LoadActionSuccess(contents);
              }),
              catchError(() => {
                // do something
              })
            );
        })
    )
  ;

  constructor(private someService: SomeService, private actions$: Actions) { }
}
```

**SearchReducer** will handle `LoadSuccess` when we successfully fetch contents from api and `Search` action that will filter our fetched contents to return only the ones containing our search string inside content's `title` parameter. We save first fetched contents in both of `contents` and `searchedContents`. Then, on search, we will update `searchedContents` to contain only `contents` having `content.title` including the searched string.

```
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';

/** ngrx **/
import {createFeatureSelector} from '@ngrx/store';
import {createSelector} from '@ngrx/store';

/** App Models **/
import { Content } from '../models/content.model';

/** ngrx **/
import * as searchActions from '../actions/search.actions';

export type Action = searchActions.All;

export interface SearchsState {
  contents: Content[];
  searchedContents: Content[];
}

export const initialState: SearchsState = {
  contents: [],
  searchedContents: []
};

/ -------------------------------------------------------------------
// Selectors
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
export const selectContents      = createFeatureSelector<SearchsState>('search');
export const getSearchedContents = createSelector(selectContents, (state: searchedContents) => {
  return state.searchedContents;
});

export function contentsReducer(state: searchedContents = initialState, action: Action): searchedContents {
  switch (action.type) {
    case contentsActions.LOAD_SUCCESS:
      const loadContents = action.payload.map(content => new Content(content));
      return {
               contents: loadContents,
               searchedContents: loadContents
      };
    case contentsActions.SEARCH:
      const keywordContents = isEmpty(action.payload) ? state.contents :
          state.contents.filter(content => content.title.includes(action.payload));
      return {
               contents : state.contents,
               searchedContents : keywordContents
      };
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

So, updating `searchedContents` will automatically update the contents in our component.

Comment: If we added other actions such as update, delete, create content. Would we need to do those actions on both searched content and contents? For example, if a user is searching and deletes one of the searched content, we would need to delete the content from both the content and searched contents, right?

Answer (score 2):

ngrx store is the part of how you store the data. ngrx store is observable so your application flow is

Container -> Components

**Container** - wrapper component that will select data from store.
example:

```
const contacts$: Observable<contact> = this.store.pluck('contacts');
```

//*contacts$ - the dollar since is convention for Observable *//

**Component** - data visualization component, the data will be as Input(). example:

```
Input() contacts: Array<contact>;
```

> this convention is called sometime SmartComponent(Container) and
>   DumbComponent(component)

now for a data transform/mapping you can use reactive approach(Rxjs) or functional programming or whatever you want but it not related for ngrx because in your contacts component the data as exist.

**DEMO FOR YOUR SCENARIO:**

contacts.container.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'contacts-container',
    template: `
    <contacts-list [contacts]="contacts$ | async"></contacts-list>
    `
})

export class ContactsContainer {
    contacts$: Observable<[]contact> = this.store.pluck('contacts');
    constructor(
        private store: Store<applicationState>
    ) { }
}
```

contact-list.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'contacts-list',
    template: `
        <input type="text" placeholder="write query" #query>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="contact of contacts | searchPipe: query.target.value">
            </li>
        </ul
    `
})

export class ContactsListComponent {
    contcats: Array<contact> = [];
    constructor() { }

}
```

i use searchPipe for data transform ( custom pipe )  but is only example for data transform you can do it else.

Good Luck!

Comment: Very clear. I prefer this answer to Andrea's. Load the data into the component (using NgRx if you like). Then do with it what you need, within the component; such as filtering. Using a pipe works great with the dynamic update of content from using Observables, because anything that comes out of the Observable stream goes into the pipe and you can chain pipes for very easy adaptation of your needs, without messing further with NgRx concepts or worrying about how data is stored and refreshed. How to implement custom filters is easy to google too :)