# Using RxJS CombineLatest with searching or selection

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, combinelatest

In my application, I'm using NGRX and RXJS. I have a window where a user can filter order, either by typing a free form text into a textbox, or clicking an  order item on the page to view the details.

I have two observables which I want to call my store and get the details by filtering either ways, but I would like to use the combineLatest function to simplify my code. The text search passes in a string to search on, while the click passes in a number id. I have this already in my code:

```
//Text search
 this.valueChanges = this.search.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(170), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.hasValue = value.length > 0;
        this.store$.dispatch(new QueryAction({ value }));
      });

//Item click
      this.clickChanges = this.selected$.subscribe(value => {  
        let Id = value.id.toString();    
        this.store$.dispatch(new QueryAction({ value: Id }));
      });
```

My question is how can I simplify this code to use combineLatest since both are very similar action and the implement searching of items stored in the store to filter based on text typed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer the question in two parts, you want to combine does two streams and trigger the QueryAction that should be fairly simple like

```
const searchStream =  this.search.valueChanges
  .pipe(debounceTime(170), 
        distinctUntilChanged(), 
        filter(value => value.length > 0)
        );
const clickStream = this.selected$.pipe(map(value => value.id.toString());
merge(searchStream, clickStream)
.pipe(tap(value => this.store$.dispatch(new QueryAction({ value: value }), 
      takeWhile(() => !destroy) // make destroy= true in ngOnDrestroy()
).subscribe();
```

Notice I use merge instead of combineLatest, this is because the later will expect for both streams to produce something before it allows the action to be fired, and you will receive both values, what you want is if either the search or the click produce an event then the action should trigger which is why I use merge.

Now I will recommend you to revise the way you are approaching this, not sure if you have read about the dumb vs smart philosophy, google it if you haven't it helps a lot when you use ngrx,  check the ngrx example app https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app,for me that was the best doc .
If I understood well what you want to achieve, I will have a dumb component for the input search (this I imaging is a sort of suggestion box that autocomplete the item ) which outputs the query event when an option is selected via click or enter, and the item list page will be another dumb component that outputs a query event when click, each event will be bound to the same method in the container (smart component) which will dispatch the QueryAction
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks fot the response. I will try this soon and i have also looked at the app previously. I actually have a single component that can perform search or click and this handler is also bound to it. I dont understand how the store will understand what to do when i call the dispatch. To know to search by text or to simply retrieve by an id? Do i have to pass in an additional parameter? We can chat if it would be too long. Thanks

Comment: In that case then you need separate actions a SearchAction(query) and a LoadAction(id), The search if all the elements are in the store use a selector in the reducer to implement a search, if they are in a backend use an effect to handle the search action and store the results in the store, see https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app/app/books, the books has a search section done by a backend search, it should be similar to what you need

Comment: This has really helped me, but I got stuck along the way, and I hope you don't mind if I ask a maybe stupid question. I'm using this example as well as that in the book,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191872/ngrx-4-how-to-filter-current-loaded-data    but I have normalized my state to use a hashtable instead of an array which is the recommendation from several examples for fast. I was able to implement searching of the dictionary using map/filter by that yields an array. How do I convert an array back to a dictionary and put it back in my state which is of type dictionary? thanks.